# Compiling Java using multiple libraries using a post-build script

Tags: java, batch-file, compilation

I am trying to compile a JAVA project via Perfect Developer (IDE), which comes with a post build .bat file, which holds some check lines and the path to the **PerfectRuntime.jar**.
I need to include -> tell the compiler, that I also want to include the **mysql-connector-bin.jar** library as well, since I need it for some database interaction.

The part that probably needs to be altered:

```
echo Compiling Java files
"%PD_JDK_BIN_PATH%javac" -d .\classes -classpath ".\classes;.\src;%PERFECTLIB%" .\src\%PD_PACKAGE_NAME%\*.java %3 %4 %5 %6
if errorlevel 1 goto ERROR
```

You may also check the whole postbuildjava.bat file: http://pastebin.com/WDkYaPQY

Comment: what is your question here?

Comment: I want to include another library (mysql-connector-bin.jar) to pass it to the javac, so the final *.jar is compiled with both libraries.